# Git - "edit" command for windows?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm learning git on Windows from a pdf and I saw that there is command named `edit` to edit files, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my PC. It replies a message `sh: edit: command not found`. How can I solve my problem? I want to edit file from the terminal. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for my previous mistake. On that time I was new here and thus I couldn't understand everything clearly. Now I am unable to post a new question and I came to edit this post. Please help me on this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused.  You'll want to install [vim](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/vim-editor-for-windows/) or [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/faq.html) if you want to edit in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe, so you are saying if I install emacs will it solve my current problem?

Comment: In a sense.  I'm still not familiar with `git edit` but simply opening and editing the file in emacs will work.

Comment: I can edit files through notepad++ but I want to edit from command line. Files opening with other programs doesn't matter.

Comment: You could just add notepad++ to your path, and open them through that, otherwise, you could use vim or emacs.

Comment: so the 'edit' command will not work on git? I already added notepad++ to my system path

Comment: I'm not sure where you found this pdf, but I don't even think there is a `git edit` command.

Comment: That error message suggests it's just "`edit file`", not `git edit`, and is clearly shorthand for... edit the file. (voted to close)

Comment: @Wooble, can you please vote for reopen the question again? I didn't understand the community standard that time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't heard about git edit command.. maybe it was saying about editing commit messages.

1) if you want git to launch custom editor while editing commit messages you can try configuring git to use it (configuration for emacs editor):

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

2) if you want just to quick edit your files from command line just tipe in there

```
notepad.exe patch_to_file
```

(or some other editor exec file)

anyway I personally recommend to read http://git-scm.com/book instead of some strange pdfs